# Как выводить в консоль сообщения о действиях бота с понятным интерфейсом?

Tags: python, логирование, telebot

Имеется следующий код. Как можно настроить telebot.logger,, чтобы вывод был максимально простым?

```
import logging

logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

[image: Получается примерно такое]

И.. Чтобы получилось примерно следующее

```
User: Как я могу получить список команд?
Bot: Используйте /Help
User: Благодарю.
```

Comment: Убрать `telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` и использовать свое логирование в обработчиках

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, можете дать какой-нибудь кусок кода для последующей работы?

Comment: я в своих скриптах использую логгер в консоль и в файл: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/1b037320ec1140fabfae615dee5902b708946438/logger_example.py#L7 Если хотите настроить формат вывода логов, то меняйте строку в `logging.Formatter`

Comment: Спасибо, а как я могу получить информацию в консоле о том что написал пользователь боту? По всей видимости нужно что-то делать с `logging.DEBUG`

Comment: В обработчиках сообщений боту. При создании бота вы в коде пишите какие функции должны вызываться. Добавьте в вопрос ваш код бота (кнопка `править`), иначе это будет гадание как у вас там сделано и как сделать так, чтобы было по другому

Comment: Дополнил. Нужно лишь сделать вывод в консоль сообщение от юзера. В моем случае /start, /help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте, возможно это натолкнёт Вас на своё дополнение

```
def log(message):
    print("<!------!>")
    print(datetime.now())
    print("Сообщение от {0} {1} (id = {2}) \n {3}".format(message.from_user.first_name,
                                                      message.from_user.last_name,
                                                      str(message.from_user.id), message.text))
```

вызывайте данную функцию в том месте где требуется лог, например:

```
@bot.message_handlercommands=['start'])
def cmd_create(message):
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи название задачи')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, create)
    log(message)
```

в консоли будет что-то вроде этого:

```
2020-04-23 14:18:13.696639
Сообщение от %Fname% %Lname% (id = %ID%) 
/start
```